# Range of $\ln\lvert \sqrt{1+x^4}- x^4\rvert$

Tags: calculus, functions

I know that the range of $\ln$ function is $\Bbb R$ but the answer key of the above question says it is into... I have tried using Desmos for the graph but it  was of no use

Comment: Of course Desmos was no use. Your expression is equivalent to $0$.

Comment: By the way, the domain of $\ln$ is not $\Bbb R$. It's $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: But $\ln\lvert (1+x^4) - x^4\rvert=\ln( 1)=0$. So the range is $\{0\} $, or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: In case you actually meant to type $\ln|(1+x)^4-x^4|$, consider what happens at x=-1/2.

Comment: You don't really mean $(1+x^4)-x^4$, do you?

Comment: thank you Dr.MV im sorry i did not tyoe the expression correctly in the first go

Comment: So, that expression is equivalent to $0 = ln(1) = ln\lvert 1 \rvert = ln\lvert 1+(x^4-x^4) \rvert = ln\lvert (1+x^4)-x^4\rvert$

Check the argument for the logarithm, maybe you typed something wrong